# Op Amp breakdown

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics

I have read many datasheets of different types of op amps but non of them mentioned the breakdown voltages. For instance, when using an op amp as a comparator, what is the maximum input voltage one can apply to the V+ and V- before it burns out!
Is there any operational amplifiers that can support 100 volts or higher ? And how much does it cost ?

Comment: Convenient datasheet in my browser history: http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/lm2902-n.pdf Absolute Maximum Ratings are given for the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Unless otherwise stated there are no differential voltage limits except those (usually) imposed by individual limits on the pins.

For example the first 100V supply op-amp I looked at would be okay with 100V between the inputs **provided** neither was outside the supplies.

Take care that some op-amps can allow significant current to flow between the inputs for large differential input voltage, even if it is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

in op-amp you dont need use 100volt input directly, you can use just a sample of your (100v) inputs
and maximum input for op-amp in datasheet identified with V+ and V- in "maximum rating"